# K&R - Understanding Floating Poin Numbers - Base, Mantissa, and Radix

Tags: c, header, floating-point

I'm reading the K&R Appendix, B.11 "Implementation-defined Limits:  and ", and trying to better understanding the floating-point constants they have defined here. In particular, I'm getting confused by the definition of these three constants:

FLT_RADIX    -- "radix of exponent, representation, e.g., 2, 16"
FLT_MANT_DIG -- "number of base FLT_RADIX in mantissa"
FLT_MAX_EXP  -- "maximum n such that FLT_RADIX^n-1 is representable"

Through some reading, my (perhaps incorrect) understanding of "mantissa", "radix", and "exponent" are as follows:

Given 1.2345 x 10^-3: 1.2345 is the mantissa, 10 is the radix, and -3 is the exponent.

If my understanding is correct, in this instance FLT_RADIX, the "radix of exponent", would be 10. FLT_MAX_EXP would be the largest number of digits representable. If the system could only represent 6 digits, FLT_MAX_EXP would be 7 as 1 x 10^7-1 would have 6 digits.

What makes me think I have all the above wrong is the definition of FLT_MANT_DIG. "Number of base FLT_RADIX..." makes me think that FLT_MANT_DIG is 10 as well. However, it goes on to say "...in mantissa" which makes me think it is something entirely different.

Another source, cplusplus.com (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/), seems to define FLT_MANT_DIG as something different entirely, "Precision of significand, i.e. the number of digits that conform the significand", which I understand in itself but can't seem to relate to the K&R definition.

Help on this would be appreciated, and a concrete example even more so. I can find plenty of information on radix, mantissa, floating point numbers, etc., but none that is helping me understand this more concretely. Also, I apologize if my question is a little winding and vague but I feel lack the necessary understanding to even ask a properly-worded question in this case.

Comment: upgrayedd: the two D's are for a double dose of double precision.

Comment: Although I have my doubts about directing people to it in general, given the type of interest you are showing, try reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Michael Burr - I love it, is there any way to add a signature line here?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - Thanks for the link, I've bookmarked it as a definite read

Comment: I think I may have answered my own question in re-reading the wikipedia entry for this. FLT_MANT_DIG -- "number of FLT_RADIX-base digits in the floating-point significand for types float, double, long double respectively". So, in my example, FLT_MANT_DIG would be 5 as there are 5 base-10 digits in my mantissa. This seems to agree with the K&R definition which is, in my opinion, a little awkwardly-worded.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @upgrayedd “signatures”? No. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you already answered, FLT_MANT_DIG is the number of digits in the mantissa. I just want to quote some points:

- There are several floating point types in C, usually: float, double and long double. The constants you write are just for the float type, except for FLT_RADIX that is common for all floating point types. There are other constants to describe the other types.
- Computers usually use base 2 (or radix 2) floating points (i.e. FLT_RADIX is pretty sure 2), as defined by IEEE (is not difficult to google the exact IEEE representation of float, double and long double types)
- The 2 parts of a floating point have a reserved amount of bits (i.e. base 2 digits). I said 2 parts (mantissa and exponent) because the base is fixed.
- As the exponent has a limited amount of bits, the maximum presentable floating point is limited by this. FLT_MAX_EXP is the greatest exponent a float variable can support, not the number of digits representable in the mantissa (the latest is FLT_MANT_DIG, as said before).
- Of course you can represent smaller number, for example, if FLT_MANT_DIG is 24, you can represent a number with 20 digits of mantissa, but a number with 25 digits will be rounded to fit the 24 digits.

By the way, in your radix-10 example, if you space for 6 digits, the greatest number you can represent is 10^6 - 1, not 10^7 - 1.

I recommend you to study how floating points formats represent negative numbers, and rare values like infinite and NaN.

Comment: Thank you for adding to my question and clearing up some of the other misconceptions I had.